# How to apply custom fields' names in related data in Yii2?

Tags: model, field, yii2

Inside model (Products for example) I have public function fields to mask DB fields

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = [];
    $fields["name"] = "p_name";
    $fields['price'] = "p_price";
    return $fields;
}
```

This works great. When I request data from model I always get name and price attributes only. However this products are related via relation table and I get theme like this (still inside this model):

```
public function getUserFriends() 
{ 
    return $this->hasMany(Products::className(), ['id' => 'id_pr_2'])->viaTable("product_rel", ['id_pr_1' => 'id'])->where->asArray();
}
```

Which works great but does not apply fields function. I know that there could be solution to call function fields and set select for those fields only.

```
$select = [];
foreach($this->fields() as $out_field => $db_field) {
    $select[] = $db_field." AS ".$out_field
}
$selectString = implode(", ", $select);
```

As far as I know YII2 this is so not OK! I believe there should be generic solution. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the name of the fields in the related model if you want.

It also depends where you want to show the fields (if you do not want to change the related model anyway), GridView for example allows you to rename the column names, I think DetailView does the same and in forms you can also rename the labels if that is your cup of tee.

Comment: Hi! This one is for rest api and I really don't like the idea to handle it manually. The first suggest (in related table did not work for me). Any suggestions?